# override master project generating output directory

Tags: gradle

In gradle, if I have a master project and two subprojects, can I have the master project NOT generate output directory at all?  I already override it so no .classpath and .project is generated as the master is never an eclipse project(which makes it very easy to import 5 projects into ecipse as you just click the master project instead to import which auto imports the 5 children but ONLY if not .classpath/.project exist in master).

My full gradle build file is on this post

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14594074/gradle-command-line-ordering-not-working-in-this-case-or-source-dirs-being-ignor

and currently, gradle generates a very empty jar except for manifest in "output/libs"(I overrode the build dir as we have a file with the name build that conflicts).

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you might be applying the `java` plugin to the root project (e.g. via `allprojects { ... }`. If the root project doesn't have any Java code, you should only apply the plugin to `subprojects { ... }`.

Comment: ah, yeah, I think that is the reason, I check tomorrow.